# Can't get email with react-facebook-login

Tags: reactjs, facebook-graph-api

I'm building a login component in my react-app using react-facebook-login, but I can't get the user's email (or the birthday... or the gender...)

I'm implementing it like this:

```
<FacebookLogin
appId="<<APP_ID>>"
autoLoad={this.state.facebookLoad}
fields="first_name, last_name, email, picture, birthday"
scope="public_profile, email, user_birthday"
returnScopes={true}
callback={this.facebookResponse}
onFailure={() => this.fbhandleFailure()}/>
```

I'm being specific with which fields I need, and also with the scope... But for some reason I think the scope is being ignored. I checked with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and it shows me two debug messages:

[Debug messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVBpx.png)

Can anyone help me?
Thank you very much.

Comment: its about their privacy u cant get untill they provide and there's no need that every user of facebook must have mail id

Comment: I know :( But for now I'm just testing with my facebook account. And the login does not asks for my email or my gender, it says it will only get my name and my profile picture

Comment: since facebook face many privacy issue they made all the datas secret even your login code will work on ur local and **HTTPS** protocol not in http

Comment: are you trying with a user who got a role in the app?

Comment: Yes, with mine. I'm the admin...

Answer (score 1):

use this link(https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and Get Token -> Get user access token -> check whatever you need under 'User Data Permissions' eg 'email'